# TravisCI: Run after_success on a specific branch

Tags: travis-ci

I would like to know how to run an `after_success` script only for a specific branch.

I am using a custom script to deploy the app after build passes. I would only like to run this when on `prod` branch.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
#1

after_success:
  - # some deployment script
  on: prod

#2

branches:
  only:
    - prod
    after_success:
      - # some deployment script
#3

after_success:
  branches:
    only:
      - prod
  - # some deployment script
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I solved it by writing a simple script using `TRAVIS_BRANCH` [environment variable](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#Environment-variables) and executed the script in `after_success`

*.travis.yml*

```
after_success:
- ./deploy.sh
```

*deploy.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "prod" ]; then
  // do the deploy
fi
```

Comment: Notice that during your deploy.sh script, if a command returns a non zero code, the build will still be marked as a success

Comment: Remember to make the script executable before_install: - chmod +x deploy.sh

Comment: **Notice** that this also triggers on pull requests targeting that branch. You may also want to use `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST`

Answer (score 18):

You can also do this by using the [script provider](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/) in the deploy phase of your build. This approach is a bit cleaner but only allows one command, unlike `after_success`.

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: # some deployment script
  on:
    branch: prod
```

Comment: much cleaner way