# How can I use an environment variable to specify branches to build in .travis.yml?

Tags: travis-ci

In the TravisCI webapp, I've specified an environment variable called "BUILD_BRANCH".  I would like to use this variable in the .travis.yml branch declaration, but TravisCI is reading it as a literal string "$BUILD_BRANCH".

I've looked for examples and references of this type of usage online and couldn't find any.  I've also emailed them for support but they haven't gotten back to me yet.

```
branches:
    only:
        - $BUILD_BRANCH
```

I've tried both "$BUILD_BRANCH" and "${BUILD_BRANCH}".

Comment: The answer here: will be sufficient for what I need, but I'd like to be able to do what I'm asking in the question.  (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338562/travisci-run-after-success-on-a-specific-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are expanded in the build, not in the place where the build matrix is expanded in jobs to be run. You would need to hard code this value.